# Looping with animations

Tags: swift, loops, animation

I have this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //'img' is a picture imported in your project
    self.mrock.image = UIImage(named: "bird")
    self.rrock.image = UIImage(named: "rock2")
    self.lrock.image = UIImage(named: "rock3")
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    if rockNamesArray[1] == "rock2"  {
    let firstPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mrock.frame = CGRectMake(167, 600, CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.mrock.bounds.size.height))
    })}

    if rockNamesArray[2] == "rock3"  {
    let secondPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.rrock.frame = CGRectMake(220, 600, CGFloat(self.rrock.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.rrock.bounds.size.height))
    })}

    if rockNamesArray[0] == "bird"  {
    let thirdPos: CGFloat = 300.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.lrock.frame = CGRectMake(115, 600, CGFloat(self.lrock.bounds.size.width), CGFloat(self.lrock.bounds.size.height))
    })}
```

And I would like to know how to make it so that when the png reaches the end of the screen, that it goes back to its original position, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can pass a completion closure to `UIView.animateWithDuration` that will be executed once your animation is complete. In the closure you can make the view return to its original position, for example:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let originalFrame = lrock.frame

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3.0, animations: {
        lrock.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 115, y: 600), size: lrock.frame.size)
    },
    completion: { _ in
        lrock.frame = originalFrame
    })
}
```

Comment: would I use CGPointMake to get it to the original frame or something else?

Comment: The original frame would be, for example, where `lrock` before you ran the animation. I'll update my answer to go into a bit more detail.